cannot connect to vncserver on ubuntu 24.04 (tigervnc)
On a small PC with ubuntu 24.04 installed, I installed tigervnc.
When I run vncserver, I see this message.
etri@PCIeHost04:~$ vncserver :2

New Xtigervnc server 'PCIeHost04:2 (etri)' on port 5902 for display :2.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.e3gOh3/passwd :2 to connect to the VNC server.


=================== tail /home/etri/.vnc/PCIeHost04:2.log ===================
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraAccessEnable
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraAccessDisable
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraAccessToggle
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NextElement
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86PreviousElement
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AutopilotEngageToggle
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MarkWaypoint
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Sos
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NavChart
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86FishingChart
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86SingleRangeRadar
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86DualRangeRadar
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86RadarOverlay
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86TraditionalSonar
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ClearvuSonar
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86SidevuSonar
> Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NavInfo
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
Terminated
X connection to :2 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

Wed Dec  4 14:46:39 2024
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 3741... success!
=============================================================================

I tried with gnome-session option like this but it also got terminated.
etri@PCIeHost04:~$ vncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/gnome-session -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -geometry 3840x2160 -localhost no :2

New Xtigervnc server 'PCIeHost04:2 (etri)' on port 5902 for display :2.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.DeT7bl/passwd PCIeHost04:2 to connect to the VNC server.


=================== tail /home/etri/.vnc/PCIeHost04:2.log ===================
=============================================================================

Session startup via '/usr/bin/gnome-session' died with signal 15!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session died with signal 15!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 3910... success!

How can I make it work?

You're using X11, right? Not Wayland?
